# How do I comment multiple lines of code in Script Editor

Tags: applescript

By prefixing `--`, I am able to comment individual lines of code however I would like to be able to easily comment multiple lines of code as well, preferably with a keyboard shortcut.

I have tried…

- command+/ or command+option+/, which are common shortcuts in other applications but neither of them worked in Script Editor
- right-click menu
- Edit, Script, Format menus

Am I blind or it just by design that Script Editor doesn't support a handy way of commenting code?

Comment: What happens if you begin the comment with two consecutive dashes, ie `--`?

Comment: You are correct, and it’s aceptable for commenting one or two lines but when I need to comment 10 or more I wish I had a more user friendly way like hotkey.  
Did I understand correctly that you don’t know such way of commenting or it’s not exist?

Comment: No, you do not understand correctly. On my computer, when I select text in script editor, I can right-click and there is a `comment tags` item which wraps the selection in `(*` and `*)` which makes everything between into a comment. FWIW, I rarely use it and typically type out whichever comment tag I think is appropriate. There is also a third character tag… the `#`.  I have no idea where your 'classic' shortcuts come from but they've never done this for me. As with most menu commands on a mac, if you want to add a keyboard shortcut, you can do so through various means.

Comment: As mentioned, you can do it via the context menu. You could also create a keyboard maestro (paid app) shortcut for "Cmd + /" to programmatically trigger that menu if there's multi line selection, or just comment/uncomment a line. I rarely use it but it's there when I need it along with the duplicate lines, move line etc.

Answer (score 2):

Enclose your multiline comment in parentheses/asterix pairs: `(* ... *)`. For example:

```
(*
  This is a multiline comment
  in Script Editor.
  Not particularly intuitive,
  But there you go…
*)
```

I don't know why they settled on that; might be a holdover from development.

So far as I know there's no menu or keyboard shortcut for commenting. But if you really want it automated you could probably write an AppleScript to do it.  Script Editor is scriptable.

---

Edit: Per @vadian in comments, selecting the lines in Script Editor  then right-clicking and choosing 'Comment Tags' will add in the correct multiline comment tags. Somehow I looked everywhere but there…

Comment: There is one. Select a line or a region, then right-click > Comment Tags

Comment: @vadian: D'oh! missed that entirely.  Thanks.  I'll add it to the post

Comment: It even uncomments the region if the region is already commented out.

Comment: @vadian: only if you select the comment tags. If not, it just adds a new nested set of comment tags.

Comment: Yes, of course you have to select the lines with the enclosing tags.